# Inject Activity into another dependent class

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'v been trying for some time now to get my dagger2 code setup correctly in my project, but I can't seem to figure out how do it correctly. My app roughly looks like this:

```java
class MyApplication : DaggerApplication() {
...
}
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {
...
}
abstract class BaseFragment() : DaggerFragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
...
    fun <T : ViewModel> getViewModel(c: Class<T>): T = getViewModel(c, requireActivity())
    fun <T : ViewModel> getViewModel(c: Class<T>, owner: ViewModelStoreOwner): T{
        return ViewModelProvider(owner, viewModelFactory)[c]
    }
}
class AConcreteFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: AViewModel

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = getViewModel(AViewModel::class.java)
}
class AViewModel @Inject constructor(private val someApiManager: SomeApiManager ) : ViewModel() {
...
}
class SomeApiManager @Inject constructor(private val activity: MainActivity) {
...
    fun authenticate(){
        3rdPartyLibrary.openLoginActivity(activity,...)
    }
}
```

Before I introduced `SomeApiManager` which depends on `MainActivity` everything worked fine. Then I had dagger2 setup to something like this:

```java
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ApplicationModule::class,
        FragmentBuilder::class,
        ViewModelModule::class,
        ...
    ]
)
interface ApplicationComponent: AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
...
}
@Module
public abstract class FragmentBuilder {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector()
    abstract fun bindAConcreteFragment(): AConcreteFragment?
    ...
}
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
...
}
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(AViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun aViewModel(viewModel: AViewModel): ViewModel
...
}
```

But how should change my dagger2 code to be able to provide `MainActivity` to `SomeApiManager`?

Comment: Injecting activity anywhere is a bad idea. It will open the box of memory leaks if care is not taken. Most probably what you want is to pass context. If you want to execute some function in the activity from the apimanager, then consider doing that in the viewmodel or pass some callback/lambda to the apimanager

Comment: The problem is that ApiManager uses a 3rd party library that requires that you pass an Activity to one of its methods (which it uses to start it's own authentication activity). Can I get around that somehow?

Comment: @denvercoder9 forgot to tag you

Comment: `@Singleton ViewModelFactory` -> You can't access your Fragment/Activity from a higher scope. `ViewModelFactory` doesn't need to be a singleton. Remove that annotation and it should/might work.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak You're absolutely right. I did not scope things sensibly when trying to modify my dagger code earlier. I got it to work now :)

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidMedenjak mentioned I did not scope things correctly. My modified dagger2 code now looks like this:

```java
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ApplicationModule::class,
        ActivityBuilder::class,
        ...
    ]
)
interface ApplicationComponent: AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
...
}

@Module()
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        FragmentBuilder::class,
        ViewModelModule::class
    ])
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity?

}

@Module
public abstract class FragmentBuilder {
    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector()
    abstract fun bindAConcreteFragment(): AConcreteFragment?
    ...
}

@ActivityScope
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
...
}

@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(AViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun aViewModel(viewModel: AViewModel): ViewModel
...
}
```

Not sure if it it's entirely correct, still not fully grasping everything that's going on. But it does work.